# Antisymmetric and irreflexive relation which is not asymmetric

Tags: relations

Can anyone give me a counterexample for a relation $R\subset M\times M$ for the statement $$R\text{ antisymmetric} \wedge R\text{ not reflexive}\implies R\text{ asymmetric}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because a relation is asymmetric if and only if it is antisymmetric and not reflexive.

To see that your implication is always true, we could check the contrapositive statement: If R is symmetric then R is not antisymmetric or R is reflexive. This is easily seen to be true since if R is symmetric and anti-symmetric, it is a sub-relation of the equality relation, in which case it is obviously reflexive.

Comment: Thank you for the second part - i was totally confused here.

Comment: I just got a question right now. What aboout $M=\{1,2\}$ and $R=\{(1,1),(1,2)\}$?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic What about it?

Comment: Isn't this example antisymmetric, not reflexive and **not** asymmetric? If not, why?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic But it *is* asymmetric, since it contains (1,2) but not (2,1).

Comment: I see it now. Let's forget what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer is yes, since a relation is asymmetric if and only if it is antisymmetric and "irreflexive". There are three distinct properties of a relation, reflexive, irreflexive, and neither reflexive nor irreflexive. Plus, M = {1, 2} and R = {(1, 1), (1, 2)} is a correct counterexample. This R is antisymmetric and not reflexive but it is not asymmetric.